# On button click, How to send a dynamic mail to distribution list on certain conditions met in the custom object?

Tags: custom-button, email-template, configuration, custom

When a user clicked on custom button and meets the criteria (**Like**..For different picklist values are assigned different distribution list) then I need to send a dynamic mail . How to acheive this?
Example:

if the Picklist value is **"Budget"** then send a mail to abc, bcd users
If the picklist value is **"Budget"** or **"service"** then send to xyz user

Thanks in advance
TN Admin

Answer (score 0):

In this case create a Javascript button. 
Below sample code is written on Account Object.
In this I am checking the `Amount` and `Request_Type__c` and `Card_Type__c` fields

You can take hint from below code and implement the solution

```
var abc ='{!Account.Amount}'; 
abc = Number(abc.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"")); 

if('{!Account.Request_Type__c}' == 'Withdrawal' && '{!Account.Card_Type__c}' == '' && abc <= 49999) 
{ 

location.replace('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Account.Id}&p3_lkid={!Account.Id}&rtype=003&p2_lkid={!Account.Primary_Contact_ID__c}&rtype=003&p4={!Account.Account_Owner__c}&template_id=00X20000002Jx2A'); 

} 

else if('{!Account.Request_Type__c}' == 'Withdrawal' && '{!Account.Card_Type__c}' != '' && abc <= 49999) 
{ 

location.replace('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Account.Id}&p3_lkid={!Account.Id}&rtype=003&p2_lkid={!Account.Primary_Contact_ID__c}&rtype=003&p4={!Account.Account_Owner__c}&template_id=00X20000002Jx2A'); 

}
```

Comment: May i know are you sending the mail to distribution list as well?. if yes, please let me know. Are there any options to complete the above task?

Comment: If you have an email address for distribution list it will be easy, otherwise I think you need to add the email address of all the users in To/CC list

Comment: Is there any configurable solution for this?...

Comment: not on the click of button, automated emails can be sent from WF

Comment: How can we achieve the same functionality with VF and custom button? or we need use lex components?... **Javascript buttons are not supported by lex**